# How to pass C/C++ *(PUCHAR)(..) correctly?

Tags: c++, c, delphi, delphi-7

I need to pass C/C++ code *(PUCHAR)(..) to delphi so I can use it with no errors but I don't know how exactly to do it. At the question I made in an IRC someone told me that "*it cast to pointer to unsigned char and dereference that pointer but I don't think there is such a thing in Delphi*".

Here is an example:

```
DWORD isENABLED;

...

*(PUCHAR)(isENABLED) = 0x00;
```

In Delphi will be like this?

```
PUCHAR(isENABLED) := $00;   // Is it right?
```

I know that this question might not be properly written but I don't know how exactly to ask this.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UCHAR` is an `unsigned char`. That's `Byte` in Delphi. `PUCHAR` is pointer to `UCHAR`. That's `PByte` in Delphi.

The original code casts the `DWORD` to be a pointer to `unsigned char`, then de-references that pointer, and assigns a value to that `unsigned char`.

So the Delphi equivalent code is:

```
PByte(isENABLED)^ := $00;
```

If your Windows unit defines `PUCHAR` then feel free to write it as:

```
PUCHAR(isENABLED)^ := $00;
```